# Pass argument from Javascript into jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, casperjs

I want to be able to pass a string to the scrapeSite function so I can add it to the passedtext varible.
[Tried this but didnt work for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/QDHEN/2/)

```
function scrapeSite(passedtext) {
result = result + this.evaluate(function(){
    var text = "";      
    $('.bottom_input_area tbody tr').each(function(){               
            text = text + $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim() + ';;;;....';
            text = text + $(this).find('td:nth-child(2) a').text().trim() + ';;;;....';
            text = text + $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text().trim().replace(' :-','') + ';;;;....';
            text = text + passedtext + ';;;;....';
            text = text + '!!!!::::';
    });
    return (text);

}); 

}

casper.then(scrapeSite('sometext'));
```

As soon as I'm trying to pass an argument to the function I get:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.evaluate')

Comment: The error is probably about the `$`, might be that `jQuery` is not included in the loaded page or not accessible, but as I never used `casperjs` I actually don't know how the scoping there works. Not related to the error message but another problem: the callback that is passed to `evaluate` is executed async, so you can't use `return`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

#### Calling `scrapeSite`

Inside of `scrapeSite` you use `this` to refer to the `casper` instance. If you do that, this suggests that you call it inside of a step like this:

```
 scrapeSite.call(casper, passedtext);
```

#### evaluate is sandboxed

[`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) is sandboxed. Everything must be explicitly passed:

```
function scrapeSite(passedtext) {
    result = result + this.evaluate(function(passedtext){ 
      ...
    }, passedtext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return a function instead. Also check the context the function is running in. I presume that the `.then()` function will call the callback function with a known context which has `this.evaluate()` defined. Otherwise you might have to look into `.call()`, `.apply()`, or `.bind()` functions.

```
function scrapeSite(passedtext) {
  return function() {
    result = result + this.evaluate(function(){
      var text = "";      
      $('.bottom_input_area tbody tr').each(function(){               
        text = text + $(this).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().trim() + ';;;;....';
        text = text + $(this).find('td:nth-child(2) a').text().trim() + ';;;;....';
        text = text + $(this).find('td:nth-child(3)').text().trim().replace(' :-','') + ';;;;....';
        text = text + passedtext + ';;;;....';
        text = text + '!!!!::::';
      });
      return text;
    }); 
  };
}
```

Comment: It got rid of the error but still don't get the text. I did some outputs and noticed that after this line:  `result = result + this.evaluate(function(){`
passedtext = undefined but gets through above.